# Is it possible to demote a master node without using "repmgr standby clone" and pg_rewind

Tags: clone, postgresql-9.5, standby, pacemaker, repmgr

I am currently using postgresql with log shipping replication. I use a master/slave resource of pacemaker to deal with postgresql failover.

I was asking if there is a way to demote a master, set it as standby and keep synchronized without using "repmgr standby clone" neither pg_rewind.

In fact, I want the old master to be quickly ready to get back to master state and "repmgr standby clone" takes several minutes to recover which is too long.

I see that it is possible to use pg_rewind to synchronize faster but it implies to have wal_log_hints enable, and I afraid that this options will decrease the performances of the master. The master is already too much busy.

I try to just write the recovery.conf in data directory, the master has well turned to slave mode, however it doesn't have upstream:

`[root@bkm-01 httpd]# su - postgres -c "/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf cluster show"
Role      | Name   | Upstream | Connection String
----------+--------|----------|--------------------------------------
* master  | node-02 |          | host=node-02 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
  standby | node-01 |          | host=node-01 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr`

I wish it is clear enough, I actually a newbie in database replication. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. In fact the former-master just need to be registered after been demoted. --force should be used if node was previously registered.

```
[root@node-01 ] su - postgres -c "/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/repmgr -f /var/lib/pgsql/repmgr/repmgr.conf standby register --force"
```